# Unhandled Exception Type JSONException on previously created code everywhere in the project

Tags: java, gradle, jar

I know this sounds like a straightforward question but please let me explain a bit what I'm struggling with.

I am working on a project which relies heavily on Java, which was previously created by a company for us to use. I was tasked to make some modifications and recompile the code for a specific task.

However, when I open the project I need to modify using eclipse, I am bombarded with the following error: Unhandled Exception Type JSONException

These errors keep me from compiling the code I need to modify and it's driving me nuts.

Now, I know I could just go through the code and add either a try/catch block or a throws keyword at the beginning of the functions using JSONObjects, but there are so many files with this error that I doubt this was just an oversight of the company.

I was wondering if they are using a jar file that takes care of the JSONException error that allow the company to compile their code without any issues or if I need to go through all the code and make those fixes myself.

Can you please help me?

If you need any further information please let me know.

Thanks!

Comment: It's a bit strange, why you are getting those compile-time errors if they made it to the code-base. I mean, checked exception should either be processed (caught) or declared to be thrown to the caller. The only suspicion that comes to my mind is - do you have a `JSONException` available on the class path? is it available in the libraries/dependencies of project? Could you add some code snippet that causes those errors? picture/screenshot can be of some help in this case.

Comment: Hello @GiorgiTsiklauri thank you for your response. Unfortunately the code is in my work computer, which I don't have at the moment. I still find it strange that this error was suppressed in the original build, which I haven't touched. So there might be a jar file that suppresses that exception?